# Update rails to a specific version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

How can I update Rails to a specific version? I have Rails 3.2.2 on my local machine, but I need to update to version 3.2.3.

If I execute `gem update rails`, it will update to version 3.2.6, which is the latest.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
gem install rails --version=3.2.3
```

Or use bundler. Write in Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
```

and execute in rails root directory

```
bundle install
```

Comment: The bundle currently has rails locked at 3.2.2.
Try running `bundle update rails`