# Rails: updating to non vulnerable version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Yesterday **critical securyty error** was published, it allows to **execute arbitrary code**: [Rails PoC exploits for CVE-2013-0156 and CVE-2013-0155](http://ronin-ruby.github.com/blog/2013/01/09/rails-pocs.html)

I want to update rails project from 3.1.1 to latest version: 3.2.11

I have these lines in gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.1'
# ...
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

I changed rails version and run `bundle update`:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.11) x86-mingw32 depends on
      railties (= 3.2.11) x86-mingw32

    coffee-rails (~> 3.1.1) x86-mingw32 depends on
      railties (3.1.10)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.11) x86-mingw32 depends on
      actionpack (= 3.2.11) x86-mingw32

    meta_search (>= 1.1.0.pre) x86-mingw32 depends on
      actionpack (3.1.0.beta1)
```

I can't even update it with `bundle update rails` command.

What is the correct way to update rails? If I update rails version in gemfile and run `bundle`, there will be errors with `sass-rails`/etc versions.
What versions of `sass-rails` and `coffee-rails` should I put into this file? Where can I find this information?

P.S. What does "~>" mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101591/what-does-mean-in-a-gem-file for the `~>` ;)

Comment: Just update the rails version in your gemfile and run `bundle update rails` you don't need to change anything else

Comment: `~>` is part of Gems versioning. See "[5.2 Advanced Versioning](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16)" for more information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update rails to a specific version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993439/update-rails-to-a-specific-version)

Comment: I updated the post with `bundle update rails` response.

Comment: Did you actually install the correct version of the various Rails gems? Use `gem install rails --version=3.2.11`. Bundler can't copy something that isn't there.

Comment: A better source for the Rails security fixes is [`[SEC][ANN] Rails 3.2.11, 3.1.10, 3.0.19, and 2.3.15 have been released!`](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/1/8/Rails-3-2-11-3-1-10-3-0-19-and-2-3-15-have-been-released/)

Comment: @theTinMan *Bundler can't copy something that isn't there.* - please could you explain this a bit further? I thought bundler would download the gems from the source if they weren't installed already?

Answer (score 3):

3.2.11 is not the only safe version. There were other gems published as well that included the security fixes: 3.1.10, 3.0.19, and 2.3.15.

From the dependency on 3.1 in `sass-rails`, it looks like you were already using 3.1.10?

You can either use 3.1.10, or upgrade `sass-rails` and `coffee-rails` to a 3.2 version, but you'd also have to update your app for Rails 3.2. I'd go with 3.1.10 in your case, at least to pick up the security fix first.

Also, you asked about the `~>`. That basically means the most recent version of the gem with the same major and minor version, and a point release greater than or equal to whatever you specify, so `-> 3.1.1` is the most recent 3.1.x, but not any 3.2 version.

The bundler error was occuring because you told it to use rails 3.2, but `sass-rails` was telling it to use 3.1. Bundler doesn't know what to do when it's given contradictory instructions like that.

Comment: Thanks, this project is under development, so I think that it's better to upgrade rails to the latest version.

Comment: The problem is it can't update to 3.2.

Comment: Try changing `sass-rails` to `'~> 3.2.5'` and `coffee-rails` to `~> '3.2.2'`. Those should let you install Rails 3.2

Answer (score 2):

If you can't update your Rails version directly for some reason you might also be interested to just inject a temporary patch into `config/initializers`.

See here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-security/61bkgvnSGTQ/discussion

From the above post for Rails 3.x these would need to be run:

```
# Disable XML
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::DEFAULT_PARSERS.delete(Mime::XML) 

# Disable YAML and Symbol parsing
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::DEFAULT_PARSERS.delete(Mime::YAML) 
ActiveSupport::XmlMini::PARSING.delete("symbol") 
ActiveSupport::XmlMini::PARSING.delete("yaml")
```